# telethon запуск обработчика событий вместе с бесконечным циклом

Tags: python, telethon

Цикл не работает, ошибок нет, обработчик событий работает исправно не пойму в чем дело, ткните меня лицом в мою ошибку пожалуйста

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events
import asyncio


api_id = 8XXX451
api_hash = 'ba956exxx38cd8xxca25056'

client = TelegramClient('session', api_id, api_hash)

async def Frog():
    while True:
        await client.send_message(-100XXX36620, 'TEST')
        await asyncio.sleep(3600)


@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=("CANNEL")))
async def handler(event):
    if 'user_id=2807' in str(event.message):
        if 'text' in str(event.message):
            await event.reply('MESSAGE')



client.start()
client.run_until_disconnected()
client.loop.create_task(Frog())
client.loop.run_forever()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не знаю насколько это лаконично и правильно:
удалив строку

```
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

проблем не будет. так как цикл бесконечный ждать тоже будет бесконечно